# Angular 2 Router Link issue

Tags: angular

I have a route like this

```
path: 'something/:id/somethingElse'
```

And in my header.component.html I want to have a link to this page

I attempted this:

```
<a routerLink="['something',myIdThatIsDynamicOnComponent,'somethingElse']" routerLinkActive="active">cool link</a>
```

To be clear in header component I have variable myIdThatIsDynamicOnComponent etc but when I click this link I get can't match any routes. The examples I have found are more for links like

```
path:'something/:id'
```

And then they post array after with id

```
['/hero', hero.id]
```

But I can't seem to find how to fit this to my example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to use `[routerLink]`. Without the brackets, the value does not get evaluated. It simply uses the string value that you pass.

If after doing this you get an error about "routerLink noy being a known property of a", then you need to `@NgModule.imports: [ RouterModule ]` into whatever module you are declaring the component in.

If after that you're still getting bad routing, then try to add a slash before `something`

```
[routerLink]="['/something'
```

RouterLinks you use relative routing. So the slash makes it go to the root to check for `something`

Comment: OH! missed that but it makes sense with the console output because the route not found message had my literal variable name in it